# Crystal Report - Set Selection Formula

Tags: vb.net, winforms, crystal-reports

When I pass a report to a CrystalReportViewer, I can pass a selection formula:

```
dim viewer as new CrystalReportViewer

viewer.ReportSource = rpt
viewer.SelectionFormula = <some query string>
```

In some cases, I do not wish to display the report, instead i want to export directly to PDF file:

```
Dim file As Stream = rpt.ExportToStream(CrystalDecisions.Shared.ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat)
```

How do you pass the SelectionFormula in this instance?

For reference, i get the following error at the moment:

> **ParameterFieldCurrentValueException was caught**
>
> Missing parameter values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so I answered this one myself, the solution is:

```
rpt.RecordSelectionFormula = <some query string>
```